# How to rotate a cuboid?

Tags: python, rotation, angle

My code :

```
##defining to plot the cuboid
def plot_cuboid(center, size):
    """
   Create a data array for cuboid plotting.
   ============= ================================================
   Argument      Description
   ============= ================================================
   center        center of the cuboid, triple
   size          size of the cuboid, triple, (x_length,y_width,z_height)
   :type size: tuple, numpy.array, list
   :param size: size of the cuboid, triple, (x_length,y_width,z_height)
   :type center: tuple, numpy.array, list
   :param center: center of the cuboid, triple, (x,y,z)
   """

    # suppose axis direction: x: to left; y: to inside; z: to upper
    # get the (left, outside, bottom) point
    ox, oy, oz = center
    l, w, h = size

    ##defining the points
    x = np.linspace(ox-l/2,ox+l/2,num=10)
    y = np.linspace(oy-w/2,oy+w/2,num=10)
    z = np.linspace(oz-h/2,oz+h/2,num=10)

    ## defining surfaces and extrude them
    x1, z1 = np.meshgrid(x, z)
    y11 = np.ones_like(x1)*(oy-w/2)
    y12 = np.ones_like(x1)*(oy+w/2)
    x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    z21 = np.ones_like(x2)*(oz-h/2)
    z22 = np.ones_like(x2)*(oz+h/2)
    y3, z3 = np.meshgrid(y, z)
    x31 = np.ones_like(y3)*(ox-l/2)
    x32 = np.ones_like(y3)*(ox+l/2)

    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') ##plot the project cuboid

    #plot outside surface
    ax.plot_surface(x1, y11, z1, color='red', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)
    #plot inside surface
    ax.plot_surface(x1, y12, z1, color='white', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)
    #plot bottom surface
    ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z21, color='blue', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)
    #plot upper surface
    ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z22, color='black', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)
    #plot left surface
    ax.plot_surface(x31, y3, z3, color='green', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)
    #plot right surface
    ax.plot_surface(x32, y3, z3, color='pink', rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.6)

    ## Add title 
    plt.title('Plot_for_PSM', fontsize=20)

    ##labelling the axes
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

How can I rotate this cuboid with respect to x-axis 30 degrees, with respect to y-axis 60 degrees, z-axis 20 degrees (these are the Euler angles).

```
center =(2.1,-0.1,0.757761) 
length=0.3, 
width=0.4, 
height=0.1
```

all are in metres. As per the code in the attached image. Can you add the necessary steps of my code to be forward and write the final code and give me please. Here is the image of cuboid formed with the above program :

[image: cuboid]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You probably want to use a rotation matrix to rotate your shape by a specified angle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: I have already obtained a rotation matrix.

Rotation Matrix = 
   [[array([[1.]]) array([[-0.]]) array([[0.]])]
 [array([[-0.]]) array([[-1.]]) array([[0.]])]
 [array([[0.]]) array([[-0.]]) array([[-1.]])]]

Now how to proceed further

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem at all.